# Can't use divs from success function in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know why this won't work for me.

```
  }).success(function(data){
    if(data.status == 'success'){
            // $("#useravatar").empty();

                for(i = 0;i < data.id.length; i++){
            $("#useravatar").prepend('<div id="av'+data.id[i]+'" class="avatar">'+data.avatar[i]+'</div>');
            var dropDiv = $('#av'+data.id[i]);  // Code from here dont work. No error. tried alert(data.id[i]); and is fine.

        dropDiv.css({
        left: 130,
        top: -190,
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'inline'
    }).animate({
        left: 5,
        top: 10,
        opacity: 1
    }, 7000, 'easeOutBounce');

            }

            }

});
```

If I use this code alone:

```
  var dropDiv = $('#useravatar');  

        dropDiv.css({
        left: 130,
        top: -190,
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'inline'
    }).animate({
        left: 5,
        top: 10,
        opacity: 1
    }, 7000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

will work with that div.

My question is why the first divs are not working? How can I make it to let a div drop down with animation?

**EDIT:**

I have tried all above code in same file like that: but it didn't work also (the second function is not called or is not doing anything).

```
 function getchatuser() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../users/process.php",
       data: {getchatuser: "getchatuser"},
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       async: false
    }).success(function (dat) {
          if (dat.status == 'success') {
              //$("#useravatar").empty();
                 for (i = 0; i < dat.id.length; i++) {
                   $("#useravatar").prepend('<div id="av' + dat.id[i] + '" class="avatar">' + dat.avatar[i] + '</div>');


                dropdivs(dat.id[i]);

        }
    }

  });
  }

 function dropdivs(idDiv) {
       // alert(idDiv); ----------> just to try this and it works got 112
     dropDiv = $('#av' + idDiv);
     dropDiv.css({
                 left: 130,
                  top: -190,
              opacity: 0,
              display: 'inline'
         }).animate({
                 left: 5,
                  top: 10,
              opacity: 1
     }, 7000, 'easeOutBounce');
  }
```

Comment: What is the structure of data? Did you check to see if it made it past the first if statement after the ajax success?

Comment: success works fine i have checked it and made alert with data returned. the structure of this `data: {getchatuser: "getchatuser"}` ? its just a string.

Comment: It works for me..  Have you tried using the context with your selector?  Like `dropDiv = $('#av' + idDiv, $('#useravatar'));`

Comment: Are you adding more than one element with the same id? That would likely become an issue.

Comment: [This code](http://jsfiddle.net/5fKJf/) works just fine btw, without using id's altogether.

Comment: @Jack they are different ids.

Comment: @Jack what im guessing is maybe about time, that ajax must finish then call function.

Comment: Please post the result of `console.log(data.id)` and `console.log(data.avatar)`

Comment: Like LeGEC said, if you have for instance `var data.id = ['foo.0', 'bar.1']` it will lead to error while using jQuery selector `$('dots\\.need\\.escaping')` as jQuery uses dots for __class__ references

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if it was indented properly. Also, what does "doesn't work" mean? That's not a useful problem description.

Answer (score 2):

> - **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5fKJf/4/
>
>   - updated the code to show the bounce effect as suggested by [bdrx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908961/bdrx)
>   - updated code to use object, + fancy avatar ;)

```
    var dat = {
        id: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        avatar: ['https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/male-users-2/512/1-32.png',
            'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/male-users-2/512/14-32.png',
            'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/male-users-2/512/8-32.png',
            'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/male-users-2/512/2-32.png']
    };

    for (i = 0; i < dat.id.length; i++) {
        $("#useravatar").prepend($('<div id="av' + dat.id[i] + '" class="avatar"><img src="' + dat.avatar[i] + '" alt="" /></div>').css({
            left: 130,
            top: -190,
            opacity: 0
        }).delay(i * 50).animate({
            left: 5,
            top: 0,
            opacity: 1
        }, 1500, 'easeOutBounce', function () {

        }));
    }
```

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show how to use a separate function as in the example and to show the bouncing: http://jsfiddle.net/5fKJf/1/

Comment: why you using `$` since you see well that im using success function of ajax , its not problem on bouncing , its problem on the function of bouncing is not called .Im not sure how i will implement this in my success function

Comment: and from @bdrx im not going to bounce 100 of users , if one user comes online that only this user will drop down bouncing to the list of users exactly like SO in chat.

Comment: It has nothing to do with bouncing 100s of users; in the question you show you are adding multiple divs in a loop to the #useravatar and are trying to bounce them by calling dropdivs.  You also state that dropdivs function is being called as shown by the alert 112. Look at the jsfiddle I linked and replace your dropdivs with the function in the fiddle, and update your loop to call prependTo and dropdivs like in the fiddle.

Comment: well this was best aproach but not really what i need, anyway it will rewared to you automatically. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @echo_Me: if i can help anyway just let me know. maybe if i can look the original source i can help better...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dropDiv = $('<div id="av' + data.id[i] + '" class="avatar">' + data.avatar[i] + '</div>');
$("#useravatar").prepend(dropDiv);
```

There is no need to use jQuery selector to find an element you created earlier. Code above should be a little faster solution.

Comment: Didnt work , even the div `useravatar` didnt appear.

Answer (score 1):

This portion of the piece from original post may be issue

```
// `dat` may be `dat` (`data`) `response` from `request`,
// if `dat` does not have `status` property, i.e.g., `dat.status`,
// within `dat` ( `json` `object` ? ),
// `if` `condition` may return `false`,
// not continue to  pieces inside `if`'s `{}`
.success(function (dat) {
          if (dat.status == 'success') { }
})
```

Try this (pattern)

```
function getchatuser() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../users/process.php",
       data: {getchatuser: "getchatuser"},
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       async: false
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
             // `data` : `data` returned, ( `json` `object` ? )
             // `textStatus`, `string`, i.e.g., `success`
             // `jqxhr`, `object` 
             // if `textStatus` === `success`
          if ( textStatus === "success" ) {
             // `console.log()` `dat`, `textStatus`, `jqxhr`
             // returned from `request`
              console.log(data, textStatus, jqxhr);
             // below pieces not addressed, 
             // adjust, continue, based on `response`

             // $("#useravatar").empty();
             //    for (i = 0; i < data.id.length; i++) {
             //      $("#useravatar").prepend('<div id="av' + data.id[i] + '" class="avatar">' + data.avatar[i] + '</div>');   
             //   dropdivs(data.id[i]);
             //    };                         
          };    
     });
  };
getchatuser()
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/nqe44/

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

> How can i make it to let a div drop down with animation?

I recreated your **example** into a jsFiddle to test the scenario.

http://jsfiddle.net/ywYyR/6/

(Press RUN again after opening for first time)

```
function getchatuser() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../echo/json/",
       data: {
           json: '{"id":[3,4],"avatar":["https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/male-users-2/512/8-32.png","https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/male-users-2/512/2-32.png"], "status" : "success"}',
        delay: 1
       },
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       async : false,
       success: function (dat, textStatus) {
          console.log(dat);
          if (dat.status == 'success') {
              //$("#useravatar").empty();
                 for (i = 0; i < dat.id.length; i++) {
                   $("#useravatar").prepend('<div id="av' + dat.id[i] + '" class="avatar"><img src="' + dat.avatar[i] + '" alt="" /></div>');


                   dropdivs(dat.id[i]);

                  }
           }
       },
        error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
 }
```

This fiddle does the following:

- in the start there are 2 users.
- make an ajax call.
- after ajax call finishes with success, the data contains 2 new users.
- add the 2 users to the HTML and animate them.

What I recommend double checking is that:

- the `#useravatar` div exists when your request is returning.
- the `.avatar` class has a `position` value other than `static`.
- you have included the easing jQuery library so that `easeOutBounce` is available.

Comment: you don't recreated the scenario, you just copied my code and wrapped it inside an ajax request! ;)

Comment: I didn't said i recreated your scenario. I said i recreated your **example** and that it works. The divs are animated after being added to the DOM from an ajax request. Read closely please.

Comment: will try it when i come home.

Comment: Yes, press RUN again after loading. jsFiddle has a bug for first time ajax simulator.

Comment: No andre , about fiddle  it bouncing all users which is wrong. have you seen SO chat rooms ? if one user entered did all users bounced ?.

Comment: What you said now is different from question and it is related to the bouncing not the ajax...i will modify it to bounce in turn.

Comment: Updated the answer. Now you can clearly see that only the new users are animated. I checked the SO chatrooms and this is the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of prepending the element then selecting it you can simply use `prependTo()` and do  both in one line:

```
var dropDiv = $('<div id="av'+data.id[i]+'" class="avatar">'+data.avatar[i]+'</div>').prependTo("#useravatar");
```

Comment: Didnt work , even the div `useravatar` didnt appear.

Comment: to explain it better, im getting new users from database, and when user entered chat, his div will fall down as entered to chat.Exactly like SO chat rooms does.

Comment: you can try running one of the divs manually outside the for loop see if it works.

Comment: Well, tried outside the loop,with `var dropDiv = $('#av45');` and `var dropDiv = $('#useravatar');` No one seem to work , however if i use the animation code in other file , chat.js it work with `useravatar` div and not `av45` . `useravatar` is the main div which holds all users. so all users animated bouncing in same time which i dont want.

Comment: I try it [here](http://http://jsfiddle.net/ze8jw/) without a function it should work. But if you put it inside a for they will all animate at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try delegate event for the dynamic div ?

https://api.jquery.com/delegate/